# Where Do I Create External API functions or Classes? Proper MVC Structure for Web Frameworks

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I am looking to add multiple API's to my senior project on an MVC based framework (Laravel). I understand the basic concept of MVC, but want to make sure that I am doing things according to best practice.

Basically, I am going to have a class/function that takes a query and calls that query on a Amazon's Product API. I have seen an example of calling API's from directly within the Controller on Laravel (see http://www.phplab.info/categories/laravel/consume-external-api-from-laravel-5-using-guzzle-http-client).

Perhaps I don't understand MVC well enough. Should an external API call be in it's own class? And if so, should it be a Controller Class or a Model Class? I hope the Stack Overflow gurus can enlighten me. Let me know if I need to clarify anything!

Comment: We can not help you unless you want us to write a blog for you, any answer below will be opinionated etc. just do your research and "opinionate" yourself.

Comment: The more I learn about Software Engineering, the more I learn that opinions are high, and best practice is relative. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm hoping my first question doesn't get shut down just because of differing opinions. This question seems a little different than "What is the best editor?" but if I am mistaken than I can accept that as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends to what you want to process with external API.

- If it's a part of the business, it can be in Model (lot of people put
  the business inside the model to follow the encapsulation principle
  of OOP).
- If it's the explicit process, it should be in Controller
  (like most people do).

For example, if you have a model Transaction in bank transfer (that automatically convert the currency, it needs the external API to get the exchange rate), the external API call should be wrapped in model. So controller cannot modify the Transaction object and it will be safe.

In another hand, you can call to external API in controller, do some extra stuffs then set it back to Transaction object. It's also good because model always contains only properties. It makes application also clear enough.

They are 2 ways of use, none is absolutely right or wrong. But if you choose one, follow it, don't mix.

Another, both 2 are only ok. The better way is putting the external calls to other places (modules etc), then call it by single line in model or controller.